# Как вращать 3D куб

Tags: css

Помогите разобраться с кодом. Есть данный куб который на клик крутится, но прокрутка идёт не правильная и не могу понять почему.. Помогите отредактировать код так чтобы от центра шла прокрутка, а не под углом.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 2.2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2.2s;
  color: #EEE;
  font-family: Monaco, MonoSpace;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #1d1f20;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

small {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.text-2 {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

.cube-overlord {
  position: relative;
  margin: 200px auto;
  width: 100px;
}

.cube-overlord .display {
  display: none;
}

.cube-overlord .cube-master {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cube-overlord .cube {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg) rotateX(15deg) rotateZ(30deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cube-overlord .cube .side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.cube-overlord .cube .side:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateZ(50px)translateY(-78px) translateX(12px)rotateY(356deg) skewY(349deg) skewX(5deg) scaleY(0.92) scale(1.1);
  background: linear-gradient(#999999, #000000);
}

.cube-overlord .cube .side:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(262deg)rotateX(356deg) translateZ(73px) translateY(-76px) translateX(-55px) skewY(1deg)skewX(0deg) scaleY(1);
  background: linear-gradient(#999999, #000000);
}

.cube-overlord .cube .side:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateX(268deg) rotateY(7deg) rotateZ(261deg) rotateY(1deg) translateZ(48px) translateX(-15px)translateY(-15px);
  background: linear-gradient(#999999, #000000);
}

.cube-overlord #cube-overlord-check:checked~.cube-master>.cube {
  transform: rotateY(-360deg) rotateX(40deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CUBE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cube-overlord">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cube-overlord-check" class="display" />
    <label for="cube-overlord-check" class="cube-master">
            <div class="cube">
                <div class="side">1</div>
                <div class="side">4</div>
                <div class="side">6</div>
            </div>
        </label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что бы куб вращался вокруг центра, нужно "собирать" его вокруг этого центра. Для наглядности вращаемый элемент сделан красным.

Так же, не стоит пытаться делать глубину при помощи `skew()`, достаточно правильно сместить(`translate`) и повернуть(`rotate`).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 2.2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2.2s;
  color: #EEE;
  font-family: Monaco, MonoSpace;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #1d1f20;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

small {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.text-2 {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

.cube-overlord {
  position: relative;
  margin: 200px auto;
  width: 100px;
}

.cube-overlord .display {
  display: none;
}

.cube-overlord .cube-master {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cube-overlord .cube {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotateX(-27deg) rotateY(45deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: rgb(255 0 0 / 40%);
}

.cube-overlord .cube .side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.cube-overlord .cube .side:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateX(100px) rotateY(-90deg);
  background: linear-gradient(#999999, #000000);
}

.cube-overlord .cube .side:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(0deg);
  background: linear-gradient(#999999, #000000);
}

.cube-overlord .cube .side:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(100px) rotateX(90deg);
  background: linear-gradient(#999999, #000000);
}

.cube-overlord #cube-overlord-check:checked~.cube-master>.cube {
  transform: rotateX(-27deg) rotateY(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CUBE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cube-overlord">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cube-overlord-check" class="display" />
    <label for="cube-overlord-check" class="cube-master">
      <div class="cube">
        <div class="side">1</div>
        <div class="side">4</div>
        <div class="side">6</div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```